# Cannot extract user email addresses with the 'Get-ADUser' cmdlet

Tags: powershell, active-directory, windows-server-2008

I'm searching for a PowerShell command that returns the email addresses of Active Directory users. When I open the Active Directory, the email address of a user can be seen in the 'General' tab.

As far as I know this Information should be stored in the `EmailAddress` or mail property of the `Get-ADUser` cmdlet so I tried this:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter 'Name -eq "Jan Ondra"' | Select-Object -Property Name,EmailAddress
```

However, the returned `EmailAddress` property is empty.

Then, I had the idea that the email could be stored in a wrong property so I tried this command, which returns all properties, default and extended ones:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter 'Name -eq "Jan Ondra"' | Select-Object -Property *
```

This returns me all different kinds of properties, but none of them contains an email address.

So it looks like the Information about email addresses isn't stored in the properties.

Are there any other places where email addresses are stored and how can I extract them?

Comment: By default you only get a limited subset of properties from `Get-ADUser`. If you want you get more than that you will have to specify it with the parameter `-Properties` like this: `Get-ADUser -Filter 'Name -eq "Jan Ondra"' -Properties mail,EmailAddress` (I don't know at the moment wich one is the right)  ;-)  ... and please format your code as code in your question. Thanks

Comment: Try this : Get-ADUser -Properties *  -Filter 'Name -eq "Jan Ondra"' | Select-Object -Property Name,EmailAddress

Comment: Thanks guys, you solved my problem :-)